# Display images in different sizes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, resize, plot, gaussian

I am creating gaussian pyramid in MATLAB 2010b. I want to show images like same patterned mentioned [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ronrubin/Projects/fusion/images/gausspyr.jpg).

I tried to use `imresize`, `truesize` but getting all images  in same size. Could anybody please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use "imshow with True Size for multiple images" [FEX file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32094-imshow-with-true-size-for-multiple-images) to answer your question...

**EDIT :** The code below will produce the subplot at the bottom right part of the figure:

```
clear imagesCellArray
mand = imread('mandelbrot_set.jpg'); % read image
dim = 3;

[imagesCellArray{1:dim,1:dim}] = deal(mand); % create smaller images by imresize
 for iRow = 1:dim
    for iCol = 1:dim
       imagesCellArray{iRow,iCol} = imresize(imagesCellArray{iRow,iCol},1/(1.5*(iCol*iRow)));
    end
 end

 % plot with imshowTruesize - true aspect ratio is preserved
 margins = [25 25];
 Handles = imshowTruesize(imagesCellArray,margins);
 for iRow = 1:dim
    for iCol = 1:dim
       axis(Handles.hSubplot(iRow,iCol),'on')
    end
 end
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to convert the given code to display the images which you shown under imshowTruesize title(4th one). It is displaying the result same as the highlighted one(3rd one)..

Comment: Try the code I added to the answer, it should produce the bottom right figure. Additionally, if this answered your question you can choose to accept it by clicking the V sign just below the # of votes